# Is it possible to feed messages to react-intl by fetch/axios.get when application starting or when app is working on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-typescript, react-intl

Is any way to get and feed existing messages by axios.get or simple fetch. I have static translations in csv in project path but i have too csv translations from client in http web path.

I want to get messages from static csv and then fetch file from web and then use this in whole app.

```
translations = getTranslations(currentLanguage);
translations = await getAllTranslations(translations); // here is a problem, how to add this to translations. Here inside is axios.get


    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <IntlProvider key={currentLanguage} locale={currentLanguage} messages={translations}>
                <App />
            </IntlProvider>
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('app-root'),
    );
```